# Output is printing negative, pi approximation - Leibniz formula

Tags: python, for-loop

I was asked to write a program that ask the user the number of iterations and prints the approximation of Pi using the Leibniz formula

```
π/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + …
```

I implemented a for loop to iterate over the a list of values. However, my program is printing a negative number. Not sure why.

Can someone let me know why I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
# Initialized variables
denominator = 1
pi = 0

# Ask user's input
iterations = int(input("Please enter the number of iterations(until 1000000): "))

for i in range (1, iterations+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pi = pi + 1/denominator
    else:
        pi = pi - (1/denominator)
    
    # Increment denominator by 2 inside the loop, so that everytime the loop iterator the denominator increases
    denominator = denominator + 2

pi_approx = pi*4

# Output
print("The approximation of pi using ", iterations, " is ", pi_approx)
```

Comment: For one, you are including odd and even divisors rather than odd only.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the i starts with an odd number, so the formula you are using is -1 +1/3 - 1/5 + 1/7 ... and not 1 -1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7...

```
# Initialized variables
pi = 0

# Ask user's input
iterations = int(input("Please enter the number of iterations(until 1000000): "))


"""Just if you want (to look more professional)

if iterations > 1000000:
    raise Exception(TypeError("Number too lagre"))

while iterations > 1000000:
    print("Enter a valid number")
    iterations = int(input("Please enter the number of iterations(until 1000000): "))
    
"""

for denominator in range(0, iterations+1):
    pi += ((-1)**denominator)/(2*denominator+1)

pi_approx = pi*4

# Output
print(f"The approximation of pi using {iterations} is {pi_approx}")

#print without f-string
print("The approximation of pi using ", iterations, " is ", pi_approx)
```

If you want to keep your code as you made it first time you have this solution:

```
# Initialized variables
denominator = 1
pi = 0

# Ask user's input
iterations = int(input("Please enter the number of iterations(until 1000000): "))

for i in range (iterations+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pi = pi + 1/denominator
    else:
        pi = pi - (1/denominator)
    
    # Increment denominator by 2 inside the loop, so that everytime the loop iterator the denominator increases
    denominator = denominator + 2

pi_approx = pi*4

# Output
print("The approximation of pi using ", iterations, " is ", pi_approx)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just hack it and surround the answer with abs() function to get the absolute value and remove the negative number